# How to upload a file to Amazon S3 and get the url in response using iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used the code snippet from Amazon Sample Code. The below code uploads the data into amazon S3 bucket, but I need the URL of the upload file. Am i going in the right direction? or could someone point me the mistake I am making

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName;
    uploadRequest.key = S3UploadKeyName;
    uploadRequest.body = self.uploadFileURL;
    //uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];

    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        // Do something with the response
        AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutPut = task.result;
        NSLog(@"bftask:%@",uploadOutPut); // Upload out put gives me the following response
        return nil;
    }];
```

---

bfTask Response:

```
bftask:<AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput: 0x1706606c0> {
    ETag = "\"0aefedfa36b687a74025b1ad50f3101f\"";
    serverSideEncryption = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just need to download the file, you can use `AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest` to download a file using the SDK. Alternatively, you can use `AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder` to generate a pre-signed URL to download a file.

If you just want to know the URL of the object, the URL follows the following pattern:

```
https://<YourS3Endpoint>/<YourBucketName>/<YourObjectKeyName>
```

Any objects in Amazon S3 are private by default and not publicly readable. If you want to make it publicly readable, you need to set `ACL` on your `AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest` object.

See [Amazon S3 Bucket Public Access Considerations](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-S3/5050) for more details.

Comment: It's impressive just how bad the AWS SDKs are and how bad their documentation is. And the result object does NOTHING useful, it doesn't even give you back the final URL. Maybe Amazon drive their developers like their picker staff, and they're too busy thinking about suicide to create useful frameworks.

Comment: @theLastNightTrain - Agreed, it honestly pisses me off. Furthermore, all the documentation is months out of date and none of the examples are relevant anymore. They also don't deprecate things, they just remove entire classes which breaks everyone's code when they run a pod update. The more I try to work with the AWS Mobile SDK the more I think it's some cruel joke on us devs actually trying to work with it.